# Сохранение фотографий в галерею

Tags: android, android-camera, gallery

Хочу реализовать в своем приложении функцию добавления фотографии. Нужно чтобы фотография, которую сделал пользователь, размещалась в ImageView и была показана в галерее телефона. Первую часть я сделал, но никак не получается реализовать вторую. Я вижу файл в каталоге телефона, но он добавляется в галерею. Если кому несложно, то подскажите ещё, как создавать свой каталог в галерее телефона.

```
public File createFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    currentPhotoPath = "file://" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Функция добавления фотографии в галерею (взял из гайда Гугла https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics)

```
 private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    Log.d("camera", "galleryAddPic: image add");
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
          Photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath));
          galleryAddPic();
          Log.d("camera", "onActivityResult: photo added");
        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CATEGORY) {
            presenter.detailCategory((String) data.getSerializableExtra("category"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовали new File "другое место" (но нужно запрашивать разрешение начиная с 6.0)?

Comment: @Style-7 пробовал, не получается ничего. Разрешение я запрашиваю и для моей реализации.

Answer (score -1):

Новые файлы не сразу индексируются в галерее, потому, попробуйте их индексировать принудительно:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
          Photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(currentPhotoPath));
          galleryAddPic();

          // ScanFile so it will be appeared on Gallery
          MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                  new String[]{(Uri.parse(сurrentPhotoPath)).getPath()}, null,
                  new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                      public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                      }
                  });

          Log.d("camera", "onActivityResult: photo added");
        }
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CATEGORY) {
            presenter.detailCategory((String) data.getSerializableExtra("category"));
        }
    }
}
```